# Why does the battery get short circuited

Tags: resistors

My question is about this image:

---

[image: Schematic diagram]

---

The book explains that when t>0 the DC voltage source is short circuited. I don't understand why. If we close the swtich at t>0 we still have the resistor of 2 Ohm connected to the voltage source.

How can this create a short circuit if there is a resistor there? And if there is a short circuit, then how is it different from the first part of the question? If I look correctly, I have two resistors in series connecting to a short circuit connected to the voltage source. So how is this different from the 2 ohm resistor connected to the short connected to the voltage source?

(It's my first time posting on electrical stack exchange so if I am not following the rules exactly, please let me know.)

Comment: I would assume that 2 ohm is the internal resistance of the source.

Comment: I really wouldn't know lol. However, I just wanted to ask you how did you insert the image in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph starting "For t > 0" is misleading, unless they said earlier that the 2 Ohm resistor is the internal resistance of the voltage source.

It might be better to say that when the switch is closed, the battery and 2 Ohm resistor can be ignored by the part of the circuit from the switch to the right.

Comment: They said nothing about the internal resistance of voltage source and nothing about ignoring it just that it gets short circuited which I don't understand.

Comment: The battery is not short-circuited, but the two points that the switch connects do get short-circuited when the switch is closed.

Comment: Ok I understand that but how does this remove the whole left side of the circuit.

Answer (score -1):

The explanation in the answer is unclear and confusing. The 10 V voltage source indeed is not shorted.

Shorting an **ideal** voltage source is never a good idea, because how much current do you think will start to flow ?

What they should have written is that closing the switch separates the circuit into two separate and unrelated circuits.

On the left the 10 V voltage source in parallel with the 2 ohm resistor.

On the right the rest of the circuit with the 3 ohm, 6 ohm and inductor all in parallel (circuit b).

Comment: Well if so why should it be removed. I am still unsure what you mean

Comment: Should what be removed ? The voltage source ? That is done to show the effect of charging the inductor. Before the switch is closed, a certain DC current flows through the inductor. Then the switch closes, effectively removing the influence of the voltage source on the right side of the circuit. Then the inductor discharged through the resistors. For some people replacing the inductor with a capacitor is easier. A similar thing happens when using an inductor. Only a capacitor want to keep the voltage and an inductor wants to keep the current.

Comment: Sorry but I am still unsure of why would that be. So you are saying that everytime  I have a DC source and an inductor once the inductor has been charge I can just take off the voltage source ?

Comment: *So you are saying that everytime I have a DC source and an inductor once the inductor has been charge I can just take off the voltage source ?* Did I write that ? No I did not. I wrote: *That is done to show the effect of charging the inductor*. You're clearly not thinking about what happens in this example. Until you do it is quite useless to discuss it in the first place. Many beginners try to solve circuits by only using formulas and mathematics without realizing **what is actually happening in the circuit** with the currents and voltages. For true understanding you need both.

Answer (score -1):

> The book explains that when t>0 the DC voltage source is short circuited. I don't understand why. If we close the swtich at t>0 we still have the resistor of 2 Ohm connected to the voltage source.

The 2 ohm resistor is part of the voltage source, not something separate that's connected to it. The voltage source is short circuit, leaving only its internal 2 ohm resistor and delivering no voltage to the rest of the circuit.

Comment: That is purely speculation.

Comment: @MattYoung I don't think so, I think it's the plain meaning of the words they've used. If it's the only possible meaning, then it's clearly not speculation. So what's the other possible meaning?

Comment: Not sure where this plain meaning is, if that were the case, we'd be worrying about the inductor's DCR as well. It's an academic textbook problem with ideal components.

Comment: @MattYoung I agree that it's an academic textbook problem with ideal components. The 10V supply and 2 ohm resistor constitute the "voltage source" they're discussing. This is the plain meaning of the text, since it's what's shorted. If you think there's some other possible meaning, please tell me what it is.